# Pass datetime with time-zone objects to date-range input in shiny dashboard

Tags: r, datetime, shiny, date-range

I have a shiny dashboard below with a `dateRange()` input in which I want to pass datetimes with timezone. But when I try to convert my datetime objects to dates after having converted them to factors I get `NAs`. How could I proceed?

```
require(lubridate)
require(dplyr)

df = data.frame(timestring = c("2015-12-12 13:34:56", "2015-12-14 16:23:32"),
                localzone = c("America/Los_Angeles", "America/New_York"), stringsAsFactors = F)

df$moment = as.POSIXct(df$timestring, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz="UTC")

df = df %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(localtime = force_tz(moment, localzone))

df

df$localtime <- factor(df$localtime)

df$localtime<- as.Date(df$localtime, format = "%Y/%m/%d")

## app.R ##
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(
    dateRangeInput('dateRange',
                   label = 'Date range input: yyyy-mm-dd',
                   start = df$localtime - 2, end = df$localtime + 2
    )
  ),
  dashboardBody()
)

server <- function(input, output) {


}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Did you need `force_tzs` instead of `force_tz`?

Comment: I still get NAs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't want to convert a date object to factor. I deleted the `factor()` line and it worked fine. Also, I guess you want the user to choose the location for time zone, since you have two items in your dataframe but `start`, `end` only accept one. I added a location selector.

```r
require(lubridate)
require(dplyr)

df = data.frame(timestring = c("2015-12-12 13:34:56", "2015-12-14 16:23:32"),
                localzone = c("America/Los_Angeles", "America/New_York"), stringsAsFactors = F)

df$moment = as.POSIXct(df$timestring, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz="UTC")

df = df %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(localtime = force_tz(moment, localzone))

df$localtime = as.Date(df$localtime, format = "%Y/%m/%d")

df
## app.R ##
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(),
    dashboardSidebar(
        selectInput(inputId = "choosezone", label = "Choose your location",choices = c("LA", "NY")),
        uiOutput("selectdate") 
    ),
    dashboardBody()
)

server <- function(input, output) {
    output$selectdate = renderUI({
        location_choice = ifelse(input$choosezone == "LA", 1, 2)
            dateRangeInput('dateRange',
                           label = 'Date range input: yyyy-mm-dd',
                           start = df$localtime[location_choice] - 2, end = df$localtime[location_choice] + 2
            )
    })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1):

Factors in R can be tricky. You can't work with them in the same way you can dates, for example you can't do addition and subtraction on them.

I've got your code working, but unless you have a specific requirement for using factors I would suggest avoiding them.

```
require(lubridate)
require(dplyr)

df = data.frame(timestring = c("2015-12-12 13:34:56", "2015-12-14 16:23:32"),
                localzone = c("America/Los_Angeles", "America/New_York"), stringsAsFactors = F)

df$moment = as.POSIXct(df$timestring, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz="UTC")

df = df %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(localtime = force_tz(moment, localzone))

df

df$localtime <- factor(df$localtime)

df$localtime<- as.Date(as.Date(df$localtime), format = "%Y/%m/%d")

## app.R ##
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(
    dateRangeInput('dateRange',
                   label = 'Date range input: yyyy-mm-dd',
                   start = df$localtime[1] - 2, end = df$localtime[1] + 2
    )
  ),
  dashboardBody()
)

server <- function(input, output) {


}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

An additional issue was there were two dates in df$localtime, so I've changed the dateRangeInput to use the first date.